# I Need to get the last Non empty cell of a particular Row from excel file using InteropExcel

Tags: c#-4.0

I am using Interop Excel dll to get the non empty cell of each and every row of an excel file.

Here is the screen shot what am looking for.

[image]

Cany anyone suggest the C# code to get the Last non-empty cell of row

I am using below code. am getting last cell of row but I need last non-empty cell of a particular row.

```
       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workBook =
            excel.Workbooks.Open(filename);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet = workBook.Worksheets["Sample"];
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = sheet.UsedRange;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range last = sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
        //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range cellRange = sheet.Range["3:3", last];
        //int lastCell = cellRange.Columns.Count;
        int lastUsedRow = last.Row;
        int lastUsedColumn = last.Column;
        long lastColumn = sheet.Cells[2, 2].End(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDirection.xlToLeft).Column;
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: There are Excel functions that can be used within Excel to achieve that (i.e. get the value of the last cell in a row, or get the address of the last cell in a row). Check if you have access to those function from within c#.

Comment: I didn't get understand FDavidov. Can you please describe briefly. So, that I will implement.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this? I am facing this same issue today

Answer (score -2):

Suppose you want to get the value of the last non-empty cell in row 2, where values may appear between columns "A" and "AY". Then, you would use the Excel formula:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(A2:Y2<>""),A2:Y2)
```

If you have access to this spreadsheet formula from within C# (I'm quite sure there is an equivalent for Visual Studio), then you could use it and solve your problem.

Comment: I need it through C# not from excel. Is there any Code to get last non-empty cell from each and every row.

Comment: I suggest you google for the equivalent of spreadsheet function `LOOKUP` in Visual Studio.